# Finding hamming distance of code

Tags: math, error-detection, hamming-distance

A question asks: find the hamming distance of the following code:

```
11111  
10101  
01010  
11100  
00011  
11001
```

The answer is 2. How does this work? I thought hamming distance is only between two strings?

Comment: Are you sure it's not asking for the *minimum* distance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Hamming distance of a code is defined as the minimum distance between any 2 codewords. So, in your case, finding the Hamming distance between any 2 of the listed codewords, no one is less than 2.

Answer (score 5):

Here is some Python-code to find it automatically:

```python
code = [
(0,0,0,0,0,0),
(0,0,1,0,0,1),
(0,1,0,0,1,0),
(0,1,1,0,1,1),
(1,0,0,1,0,0),
(1,0,1,1,0,1),
(1,1,0,1,1,0),
(1,1,1,1,1,1)]

def hammingDistance(a, b):
    distance = 0
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        distance += a[i]^b[i]
    return distance

def minHammingDistance(code):
    minHammingDistance = len(code[0])
    for a in code:
        for b in code:
            if a != b:
                tmp = hammingDistance(a, b)
                if tmp < minHammingDistance:
                    minHammingDistance = tmp
    return minHammingDistance

print("min Hamming distance: %i" % minHammingDistance(code))
```

Answer (score 5):

We have a theorem that **d_min=weight(sum(all codes))**;
weight is the number of non zeros in the result string . In your example modulo add all string codes
like first column of all and second....... then we get code as **[ 0 0  1 1 0 ]**, weight of this is 2 ( no. of non zeros), i.e the minimum distance of hamming code

Comment: Do you have a source for that theorem? If you have the strings `0000`, `1000` and `1110` the minimum hamming distance is obviously `1` but your calculation would return `2` (the xor-sum is `0110`)